# Play video with powershell on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, windows-10, windows-media-player

I tried to use the code of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388995/powershell-script-to-play-video-with-windows-media-player) post.

When I use this code directly on PowerShell terminal it run correctly.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationCore
$filepath = "C:\Temp\test\Wildlife.wmv"
$wmplayer = New-Object System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer
$wmplayer.Open($filepath)
Start-Sleep 2 
$duration = $wmplayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.Seconds
$wmplayer.Close()

start playing
$proc = Start-process -FilePath wmplayer.exe -ArgumentList $filepath -PassThru
```

But when I run the code on .bat file, a cmd window appears and disappears in a few seconds and without further action.

If I run the .bat file on CMD, this errors appear:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1UsK.png)

The code inserted in .bat file is:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationCore
 $filepath = [uri] "C:\Users\??????\Desktop\small.mp4"
 $wmplayer = New-Object System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer
 $wmplayer.Open($filepath)
 Start-Sleep 2 # This allows the $wmplayer time to load the audio file
 $duration = $wmplayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds
 $wmplayer.Play()
 Start-Sleep $duration
 $wmplayer.Stop()
 $wmplayer.Close()
```

I would be most thankful if you could help me solving this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "insert the code"? Also your "start playing" line is probably meant to have a # at the start.

Comment: I have already modified the post, I was referring to a .bat file

Comment: Perhaps due to execution policy? Run get-executionpolicy in a powershell window and share the results

Comment: It would also be helpful to see the contents of the .bat file that you're using to run the script. Also if you open a cmd prompt first and then run it, you should be able to see what error is being returned.

Comment: Get-ExecutionPolicy = RemoteSigned.

Comment: The post was edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to run PowerShell commands within a .bat file (as a result the PowerShell engine isn't being used to execute the code so the commands fail).

You need to save the script as a .ps1 file, then execute it from the command-line either via it's full path name or by changing to the directory where the script exists and entering:

```
.\scriptname.ps1
```

Where scriptname is the name you saved the file at.

If you want to execute the script via a .bat file, you still need to save it as a .ps1 and then create a .bat file with the following content:

```
Powershell.exe -File  C:\path\to\my\script\myscript.ps1
```

Obviously correcting the path accordingly. Note there is no advantage to running the script this way, but one reason you might use a .bat file is if you needed to change the execution policy to allow script execution (I don't think you do in your case) as follows:

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -File C:\path\to\my\script\myscript.ps1
```

Comment: I want to use this code via .bat because I going to execute this PowerShell code with autorun system in a CD.

Comment: So then you just need to create the script as a .ps1 on the CD and call it via the autorun.bat file as I describe above.